# Animation not restarting on event for a-frame 0.9.2

Tags: animation, aframe

Good day!

I am a total noob on a-frame and I am trying to achieve a simple animation replay every time an event occurs.

I notice that on v0.8.2 with animation component it works with the same code and animations restart as I want, but on the new v0.9.2 this behavior does not happen.

```
<!--This works as i want!--> <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@^4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin:mouse"><a-box position="0 2 -2" color="blue" radius="1" foo animation="property: scale; to: 2 2 2; dur: 200; startEvents: mousedown;"></a-box></a-scene>
```

[As you can see in the animation this only works once :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMls3.gif)

Edit on request: Here is the project on glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/4aaf9ff9-4dd6-4780-bf1f-f75648f2149f

Any insights?

Thank you in advance!

Tried various versions and even fiddled with .emit js component but the behavior is still the same in v0.9.2. Animations wont replay.

I expect to replay the same animation every time an event occurs without using loop and pause controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a '>'
at the end of this line:

'src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@^4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"  /script '

That could break functionality in your script.
Hard to know because you've got all of your code crammed into one line above.
It would be much easier for us to debug if you placed your project code inside of a glitch or fiddle. (glitch.com)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I just created an example of this projecto on glich https://glitch.com/~steady-playroom

Comment: Thnks Thomas. I know now the roadblock: I`m trying to start multiple times the same animation but I need to emit the startEvent to the camera by clicking another object. Any idea on how to make that happen?

Comment: Yes. You need to make a custom component, that will be attached to the 'button' 3d object. In that component, you will have a listener, that will be triggered with a mouseDown event, which can then call the camera to perform the animation. Take a look at this glitch, which demonstrates how to do this. Just change the red ball to your camera.    https://glitch.com/~animate-button

Comment: I remixed your glitch. Check it out~ Click the tomato box.   https://glitch.com/~octagonal-bail

Comment: Nice!! Thanks a bunch this was exactly what I needed. You are going straight to project credits. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/335126cd-ea9c-41f5-9202-2db3902a0947